# What is the specific heat and latent heat of an ethanol-water mixture?

Tags: heat

How do I find the specific heat and latent heat of ethanol-water mixture? Let’s say the mole fraction of water is 0.3 and ethanol is 0.7.

I am working on a project and needed values for these and couldn’t find it.

Comment: So did you try googling 'specific heat ethanol water mixture'? That results in several good looking hits...